# Strange verbatim issue in beamer even after issuing `fragile` option

Tags: beamer, verbatim

I am trying to develop a `beamer` tutorial in `beamer`. Let us suppose that we have the following code:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{A slide with the table of contents} 
For having a slide with the table of contents, we use 
\begin{verbatim}
   \begin{frame}{Contents} %complains here if there is no space
   \tableofcontents
   \end{frame} %complains here if there is no space
\end{verbatim}
\end{frame}
```

If I do not put some spaces (not a tab), before any of `\begin{frame}` or `\end{frame}` inside the `verbatim` environment, pdflatex complains.

I discovered this, after I continued creating three to four files in ensuring that this was the cause. Why would this be happening?

For information: I am using the TexLive distribution on an Ubuntu 14.10 64 bit.

### Some more information:

```
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamer.cls
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasercs.sty
Package: beamerbasercs 2013/12/25 (rcs-revision 31cc758a62ae)
)
Document Class: beamer 2013/12/02 3.33 A class for typesetting presentations (r
cs-revision 332bfd3ce558)
```

### File list from `.log` file

```
beamer.cls    2013/12/02 3.33 A class for typesetting presentations (rcs-revi
sion 332bfd3ce558)
beamerbasercs.sty    2013/12/25 (rcs-revision 31cc758a62ae)
beamerbasemodes.sty    2013/09/03 (rcs-revision 768f2d98ca64)
beamerbasedecode.sty    2010/05/01 (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
beamerbaseoptions.sty    2013/03/10 (rcs-revision 47431932db0d)
  keyval.sty    2014/05/08 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
  size11.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2014/04/25 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2013/11/30 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.47)
  pgfrcs.sty    2013/12/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.28)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
 xxcolor.sty    2003/10/24 ver 0.1
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
beamerbaserequires.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbasecompatibility.sty    2012/05/01  (rcs-revision 67c48b3b652d)
beamerbasefont.sty    2013/10/18  (rcs-revision 72f39e01808a)
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
sansmathaccent.sty    2013/03/28
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
beamerbasetranslator.sty    2010/06/11  (rcs-revision 85fd1cc7fc42)
translator.sty    2010/06/12 ver 1.10
translator-language-mappings.tex
beamerbasemisc.sty    2013/09/03  (rcs-revision a55719c41d85)
beamerbasetwoscreens.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseoverlay.sty    2013/12/25  (rcs-revision f6bd5e3805da)
beamerbasetitle.sty    2010/09/21  (rcs-revision f0446ed0b6ae)
beamerbasesection.sty    2013/06/07  (rcs-revision 60b9fe0f342f)
beamerbaseframe.sty    2013/10/02  (rcs-revision cdc8e9a3aaac)
beamerbaseverbatim.sty    2012/08/30  (rcs-revision dfdb135076b3)
beamerbaseframesize.sty    2011/09/12  (rcs-revision 70f9d8411e54)
beamerbaseframecomponents.sty    2013/10/18  (rcs-revision 5cf6c5555a45)
beamerbasecolor.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision d1a9b48be06d)
beamerbasenotes.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerbasetoc.sty    2013/05/23  (rcs-revision 0fdf5bc43be8)
beamerbasetemplates.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty    2013/09/04  (rcs-revision 4ac715c499d0)
beamerbaseboxes.sty    2012/05/13  (rcs-revision 56972908a390)
beamerbaselocalstructure.sty    2013/09/04  (rcs-revision 4ac715c499d0)
enumerate.sty    1999/03/05 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
beamerbasenavigation.sty    2013/10/05  (rcs-revision 62be157fe783)
beamerbasetheorems.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision 7e7cc5e53e9d)
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
  amsthm.sty    2004/08/06 v2.20
beamerbasethemes.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerthemedefault.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerfontthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamercolorthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerinnerthemedefault.sty    2013/10/15  (rcs-revision 65cb471f9634)
beamerouterthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamercolorthemestructure.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
verbatim.sty    2003/08/22 v1.5q LaTeX2e package for verbatim enhancements
fixltx2e.sty    2014/06/10 v1.1r fixes to LaTeX
gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty    2012/02/07 (rev. 100) GNUPLOT Lua terminal style
    tikz.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)
     pgf.sty    2013/12/18 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14)
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
tcolorbox.sty    2014/05/28 version 3.05 text color boxes
 environ.sty    2014/05/04 v0.3 A new way to define environments
trimspaces.sty    2009/09/17 v1.1 Trim spaces around a token list
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
listings.sty    2014/03/04 1.5c (Carsten Heinz)
 lstmisc.sty    2014/03/04 1.5c (Carsten Heinz)
listings.cfg    2014/03/04 1.5c listings configuration
beamerthemeWarsaw.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerinnerthemerounded.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerouterthemeshadow.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerouterthemesplit.sty    2012/10/16  (rcs-revision 51a8c72084af)
beamercolorthemeorchid.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamercolorthemewhale.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerfontthemeserif.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
   babel.sty    2014/03/24 3.9k The Babel package
 english.ldf    2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system
inputenc.sty    2014/04/30 v1.2b Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
 fourier.sty    2005/01/01 1.4 fourier-GUTenberg package
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
textcomp.sty    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
  ts1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
fourier-orns.sty    2004/01/30 1.1 fourier-ornaments package
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
 fmlfutm.fd    2004/10/30 Fontinst v1.926 font definitions for FML/futm.
 fmsfutm.fd    2004/10/30 Fontinst v1.926 font definitions for FMS/futm.
 fmxfutm.fd    futm-extension
  ts1cmr.fd    1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
  t1futs.fd    2004/03/02 Fontinst v1.926 font definitions for T1/futs.
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
Lecture4a.out
Lecture4a.out
translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-bibliography-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-environment-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-months-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-numbers-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict    
fmlfutmi.fd    2004/10/30 Fontinst v1.926 font definitions for FML/futmi.
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
Lecture4a.vrb
  t1cmtt.fd    1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
lstlang1.sty    2014/03/04 1.5c listings language file
lstlang2.sty    2014/03/04 1.5c listings language file
lstlang3.sty    2014/03/04 1.5c listings language file
lstlang1.sty    2014/03/04 1.5c listings language file
lstlang2.sty    2014/03/04 1.5c listings language file
lstlang3.sty    2014/03/04 1.5c listings language file
lstlang1.sty    2014/03/04 1.5c listings language file
lstlang2.sty    2014/03/04 1.5c listings language file
lstlang3.sty    2014/03/04 1.5c listings language file
 lstmisc.sty    2014/03/04 1.5c (Carsten Heinz)
    utf8.def    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
```

### Minimum working example

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\title{A demo presentation}
\author{My self - the Indian guy}
\institute{Indian Institute}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{How to generate a table of contents}
\begin{verbatim}
    \begin{frame} %does not cpmplain here
    \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}
\end{verbatim}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{How to generate a table of contents}
\begin{verbatim}
\begin{frame} %complains here! 
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\end{verbatim}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The solution provided by Werner in the duplicate question/answer (namely to box the verbatim material first) will solve your problem, although you are not using `tcolorbox` here. Werner also explains the cause of the problem in his answer.